# Can I upload already-encoded content to azure media services, instead of uploading a video and then encoding it? How?

Tags: encoding, azure-media-services

I want to encode locally and upload to avoid spending money in encoding.
Is this allowed? I did not find any documentation on it.

When I simply uploaded a file to the storage, the media services account said it could not play it without the ISM file. I had to encode (was it re-encode? it was an mp4) the file I had uploaded - I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely allowed and encouraged for customers. Especially ones that have custom encoding requirements that we may not support.

You can upload an .ism file that you create along with your encoded files.  It's a simple SMIL 2.0 format XML file that points to the source files used.

It's a bit hard to find searching the docs, but there is a section outlining the workflow here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/encode-dynamic-packaging-concept#on-demand-streaming-workflow

There is also a .NET Sample showing how to do it here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet/tree/main/Streaming/StreamExistingMp4

You can see the code line at 111 that shows how to generate the .ism file  -

```
 // Generate the Server manifest for streaming .ism file.
 // This file is a simple SMIL 2.0 file format schema that includes references to the uploaded MP4 files in the XML.
 var manifestsList = await AssetUtils.CreateServerManifestsAsync(client, config.ResourceGroup, config.AccountName, inputAsset, locator);
```